Physical Significance of power density of a point source of heat
What does the power density of a point source of heat signify?
I'll illustrate this with the help of an example

Consider a sphere of radius R and thermal conductivity k with a point source kept at its centre whose power density is W. Find the temprature of the sphere as a function of distance from centre i.e. T = f(r). It's given that the sphere attains steady state almost instantly.

My Argument:-
Clearly, the point source must emit heat to its adjacent layer and then that layer to its adjacent layer and so on. Since the sphere has attained steady state, it's no longer absorbing energy and thus same amount of energy must flow through each section in unit time. So why really does the power density signify here?

What is the boundary condition at R?

The example is intended to get you to solve the steady-state conduction heat equation for spherical geometry.
Conduction involves a heat flux, and its source is a power source at the center. I wouldn’t have referred to a power density if writing this problem, since this term doesn’t make sense with a point source: What volume would I multiply the power density by to obtain the power?
The solution requires the boundary condition at the surface (representing a power sink), and this information is missing from the quoted excerpt.
Examples of power sources that could be idealized as point sources include a small amount of radioactive material, a small electrical resistor with a current flowing through it, and a small region undergoing an exothermic chemical reaction.

I presume that you have to solve a diffusion/heat conductivity equation, which does not conserve energy (i.e., some losses are implied, if not explicitly stated.) So one needs a source to maintain a steady state. I do agree that the formulation of the problem is somewhat vague.
Note that, without a source (and losses) the sphere should come to equilibrium, and the temperature should be homogeneous everywhere.

I apologise for the poor phrasing of the problem.Will update shortly
